# Inserting values from table a and id from table b to table c

Tags: mysql, insert

### I have table a that have this structure

id---subject_code---subject_name---course_id

1------sadsign-------system analysis--------1

2------comart--------communication---------1

3------algebra----------algebra-----------------2

### and table b i just want to take the stud_id

id---stud_id---stud_fname---stud_mname---stud_lname

1----1001-----------john------------long---------------smith

### and i want to automatically insert all rows in table c with a course_id that have a value of 1 from table a with a stud_id from table b with this kind of output

id----stud_id----subj_id----course_id

1----1001--------1----------------1

2----1001--------2----------------1

I hope someone can help me its my first time askin here sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO tableC ( stud_id, subj_id, course_id)
SELECT a.stud_id, b.subj_id, b.course_id
FROM tableA as a, tablB as b
Where a.course_id =b.course_id
```

*Try this may this will help*

Comment: Is it helpful to you?